# Trouble extending the Future[T] trait in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Please excuse my poor understanding of Scala. I'm just a Java developer that wants to get something working in the Play Framework. I even attempted to implement a trait using Java code, but I got even more obscure errors. I have the following Scala code:

```
package models

import scala.concurrent.Future

class SettableFuture[T](name: String) extends Future[T] {
    var assignedValue: T

    def set(newValue: T) =
        assignedValue = newValue

    //override abstract methods in Future[T]
    def ready(atMost: scala.concurrent.duration.Duration)(implicit permit: scala.concurrent.CanAwait): models.SettableFuture[T] =
        this

    def result(atMost: scala.concurrent.duration.Duration)(implicit permit: scala.concurrent.CanAwait): T =
        assignedValue

    def isCompleted: Boolean =
        false

    def onComplete[U](func: scala.util.Try[T] => U)(implicit executor: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext): Unit =
        null

    def value: Option[scala.util.Try[T]] =
        null
}
```

And here's my error:

```
overriding method ready in trait Awaitable of type (atMost: scala.concurrent.duration.Duration)(implicit permit: scala.concurrent.CanAwait)SettableFuture.this.type; method ready has incompatible type
```

Ignore the return values of the methods for now, they're nonsensical because I'm just trying to fix all the compile errors.

I simply copied the method stubs from the compile time exception when extending a trait without overriding its abstract methods and pasted them into my source file. I don't understand why I'm still getting errors. I took a look at the signature for ready() in Awaitable and it looks like the return type should in fact be the class.

EDIT: the reason why I want to implement this is because in the Promise/Future Scala API, I can only find things that let me asynchronously execute long-running, blocking tasks. What I'm after is something that lets execution of a request be suspended until something of interest sets a value in the SettableFuture instance, which completes a Promise to send a response. In this way, it's somewhat like a continuation. Anyway, here is the working code that I ended up with:

```
package models

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

import scala.concurrent.CanAwait
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.util.Try

class SettableFuture[T]() extends Future[T] {
    private final val ValueNotSet = 0
    private final val ValueBeingSet = 1
    private final val ValueSet = 2

    private val valueStatus: AtomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(ValueNotSet)
    private val onCompleteWaitHandle: CountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1)
    private var onComplete: Try[T] => _ = _
    private var assignedValue: T = _

    /** Set a value and complete this Future.
      *
      * Returns false if the value has already been set by a past call to this method.
      * Otherwise, marks this Future as complete, executes the function passed to
      * onComplete, and finally returns true.
      */
    def set(newValue: T): Boolean = {
        //set value and trigger onComplete only once
        if (valueStatus.compareAndSet(ValueNotSet, ValueBeingSet)) {
            assignedValue = newValue
            valueStatus.set(ValueSet)
            onCompleteWaitHandle.countDown()
            if (onComplete != null)
                onComplete(Try(assignedValue))
            true
        }
        false
    }

    //override abstract methods in the Future[T] trait
    def ready(atMost: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait): this.type = {
        onCompleteWaitHandle.await(atMost.length, atMost.unit)
        this
    }

    def result(atMost: Duration)(implicit permit: CanAwait): T = {
        ready(atMost)
        assignedValue
    }

    def isCompleted: Boolean = (valueStatus.get() == ValueSet)

    def onComplete[U](func: Try[T] => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit =
        onComplete = func

    def value: Option[Try[T]] = {
        if (!isCompleted)
            None
        Some(Try(assignedValue))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of the specific error you are getting, the `ready` method you are overriding has a return type of `Awaitable.this.type` - ie. the specific type of this instance of `Awaitable` (the super type of `Future`, so that in `Future`, this method is seen to have return type `Future.this.type`). For your `SettableFuture` class, this means the return type for the `ready` method needs to be `models.SettableFuture.this.type`.

Other minor problems you can expect to hit: the `onComplete` method's implementation should be `{}`, not `null`, as the latter is a return of type `Null.type`, not `Unit`, and the var `assignedValue` needs to be initialised in a non-abstract class, which can be done by adding `= _` to the line defining the variable (although you really want to make it at least `protected`, and provide an accessor which will check if it has been set - maybe by changing the variable to an `Option[T]` initialised to `None`, or else maintaining a `Boolean` flag that can be checked in the accessor, and which is set to `true` by the `set` method).

In terms of what it looks like you are trying to achieve, however, you might just want to check out `scala.concurrent.Promise`, which represents a "promise of a future result". It has a method `future` that returns a `Future`, and various `complete`, `completeWith`, and similar methods that can be used to set the `Promise`'s value, which in turn will cause the associated `Future` to become ready/completed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the Scala code working completely now. As for the Promise and Future bit, I'm not sure if that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I feel like most of that API deals with long running, blocking tasks. What I'm after is something that lets execution of a request be suspended until something of interest sets a value in the SettableFuture instance, which completes a Promise to send a response. In this way, it's somewhat like a continuation. Are you aware of anything that exists in the Scala library that does something like this?

Comment: @KevinJin That's exactly what a `Promise` is for. The code that will set the value holds a reference to a Promise `p`, which it will complete with the value at some point in the future. The computation that is waiting on the value gets a reference to `p.future` and can react to completion of the future in the usual way (registering a callback, mapping, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

The `SettableFuture` class unnecessarily mixes the two concerns that the `Future` and `Promise` traits were designed to separate:

- asynchronous provision of a value (`Promise`), and
- waiting for and reacting to that provision (`Future`)

Rather than thinking of a `Future` as an asynchronous, long-running, blocking computation, it may help to think of it simply as a value that may be provided at some future time. You can react to provision of that value in a number of ways, including registering a callback or mapping it to some other value. For example, in Play one will often suspend processing of a request with a pattern like this (in Scala):

```
def handleRequest = Action {
  Async {
    gimmeAFuture().map(value => Ok(value))
  }
}

def gimmeAFuture(): Future[JsValue] = // ...
```

The gimmeAFuture method returns a `Future`, but the request handling code doesn't care about how the value is computed. It could be

- computed immediately with `Future.successful`,
- computed asynchronously with `Future.apply`, or
- supplied by the completion of a `Promise`

As an example of the latter, the `gimmeAFuture` method might be implemented as follows:

```
def gimmeAFuture: Future[JsValue] = {
  val p = Promise.apply[JsValue]()
  // asynchronously complete the promise 30 seconds from now
  scheduler.scheduleOnce(30.seconds)(p.complete(Success(someJsObject)))
  // return the future immediately
  p.future
}
```

Of course, you could implement that method however you want. The key is that something will need to hold on to that `Promise` object and complete it with a value in order to resume handling of the request. The request handler itself *does not* get a reference to the `Promise` object, since it only cares about the value that will be computed (i.e., the Promise's Future).

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this question after finding this [link](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1977) and I realized why there was so much confusion.

I was planning on using the SettableFuture class because I couldn't find anything like it that already existed in the Play Java API. I wanted something equivalent to a TaskCompletionSource in .NET, and Aaron's answer made it really clear that Scala had exactly what I needed. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the equivalent in Play's Java API.

That link cleared up exactly why I was having so much difficulty over something that should have been so simple. Thanks all for answering my question!